# How to know which user account runs a specific windows service?

Tags: c++, windows-services, user-accounts

How can I know, by using C++ code, which user runs a specific service? The program I need to write might run under a local administrator account, so I guess there won't be permissions problems.

Is it possible?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you need the user of the currently running service or the user specified in startup parameters of the service, see [QueryServiceObjectSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379312%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [QueryServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684932%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions in Windows API respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my suggestions but I have not tried any of them.
You may use [QueryServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684935%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API with service configuration level set to SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO and then use the [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API to find the account name associated with the service. (or) You may use the [ToolHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686832%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) APIs to enumerate all the processes and figure out the user account associated with the process.